# Can the JVM automatically load an agent without specifying agentpath on the command line?

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

I have a java application packaged in a jar that I am trying to run on a Windows 10 workstation.  I am running the application using the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe -jar app.jar
```

Inside the application I check to see what flags have been passed in to the Java process using the MXBean:

```
     RuntimeMXBean mxbean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
     List args = mxbean.getInputArguments();
```

I have been surprised to see this in the list of JVM arguments:

```
 -agentpath:C:\Program Files\SentinelOne\Sentinel Agent 22.3.4.612\SentinelJava64.dll
```

How is it possible that this argument was added automatically?  Does it come from a property file somewhere?

And is it possible to disable this agent from being added?  Is there a way to suppress the defaults?

Comment: do you have Sentinel One plugin installed , if yes Eclipse will automatically add it as a java agent, to disable the agent , disable the plugin

Comment: Eventually, this feature won't work anymore. https://openjdk.org/jeps/451

Comment: @satyesht Eclipse is not installed

Comment: @boneill It does not appear that this is being dynamically loaded. I is showing up as a command line argument.  I just do not know where it came from, it was not on the original command line.

Comment: Well, “SentinelOne” is a “security software”, so it apparently does what most “security software” does, hacking into every process and modifying the system configuration, in other words, all the things they claim to protect us from. I hope that at least you or someone from your company remembers deliberately installing SentinelOne…